# Google Cloud Platform create a no organisational project using API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i am trying to create a project using API in google cloud platform with no organisation , but i can't and when i try to create an organisation they asked me to buy a domain, is there any way to pass this problem?

Comment: Please provide commands and outputs.

Comment: post https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects
with these parameters {
  "name": "hahahahah",
  "projectId": "qqqqaa89898989",
   "labels": {
    "apiai-agent": "true"
  }
}
i got this error 
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Service accounts cannot create projects without a parent.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Notice that as stated on the [projects.create API method documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) you necessarily need to have the `resourcemanager.projects.create` (permission contained within some predefined roles like the [roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resourcemanager.projectCreator)) on the specified parent of the project (which can be either an [organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) or a [folder](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders#folder-permissions) within the organization) and there is no way to bypass this.